# How to improve performance for MacOS Screen sharing to Ubuntu vino-server?

Tags: macos, unix, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I'm using MacOS Screensharing client to connect to the built-in vino-server on Ubuntu  20.04 LTS all on my local gigabit LAN. It connects reliably, however performance is pretty bad, almost unusable. To me it looks like there is almost no compression being applied. Ubuntu System Monitor reports that I'm using about 2.5Mbps, and even typing has a significant delay.

My sense is that macOS is refusing to compress the frame data and vino-server is being forced to comply with it. Is there a way to get macOS to use compression or reduce colors to improve performance? I can install a different VNC server on the Ubuntu side if that helps, but I'd much rather retain macOS screensharing at the client-end because it works so seamlessly on the other Macs I have to connect to routinely.

Comment: macOS VNC does not do compression.  You need to use a different client if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks @MarcWilson. I tried out RealVNC's VNC Viewer and that does improve things a bit, at least it is a bit more usable than before, now. I'm now using VNC Viewer for VNC to Ubuntu and continue to use macOS Screensharing for Macs. A single software would be better, but this is a working solution for my needs, right now.